# Which magic method does hasattr call?

Tags: python, methods

Which magic method method does `hasattr` call?

`getattr(__o, name)` can also be called as `__o.__getattr__(name)`

`setattr(__o, name)` can also be called as `__o.__setattr__(name)`

But what is the equivalent for `hasattr`?

I know the associated magic method for the `in` keyword is `__contains__`.

Comment: i think it calls getattr but then discards the result. something like `!!getattr(name)` in JS lingo.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr). It calls `getattr()` and catches the exception.

Comment: It may be helpful for you to know that `__getattr__` isn't directly called by `getattr`. Instead, it calls `__getattribute__`, which *might* call `__getattr__` (for attributes not found the usual way).

Comment: **No**. `getattr` is **not equivalent** to `.__getattr__`, same with `setattr`. The magicethofs are *hooks*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific dunder method for `hasattr()`. It's essentially equivalent to:

```
def hasattr(object, name):
    try:
        getattr(object, name)
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

So it's dependent on the same dunder methods used by `getattr()`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) specifically states that

> This is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an [`AttributeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError) or not.

That means that the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) are the dunders you are most concerned about.